# Dynamodb batchget giving validation error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

My DynamoDb table is defined as such with Primary Partition and Sort keys

Table name  user
Primary partition key   phone_num (String)
Primary sort key    Country (String)

I am trying to do a batchget on this table with the following parameter setup

```
var dynamoQueryParams = {
    RequestItems: {
        'user': {
            Keys: [
                {"phone_num": {"S":"+14085551212"}, "Country": {"S":"USA"}},
                {"phone_num": {"S":"+14085551313"}, "Country": {"S":"USA"}}
            ],
            AttributesToGet: [
                'phone_num', 'Country', 'createdAt'
            ],
            ConsistentRead: false
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my code with this parameter setup I get the error "ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema".

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. I have tried various combinations of things, with and without quotes, with and without the Country key but I keep getting the same error and not sure what I need to do.

Appreciate any pointers on what I may be missing here.

Thanks,
Sanjay.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how you are trying to call batchget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide the value without data type "S" on params. DynamoDB will automatically consider that as String.

```
var params = {
    "RequestItems" : {
        "user" : {
            "Keys" : [ {
                "phone_num" : "+14085551212",
                "Country" : "USA"
            },
            {
                "phone_num" : "+14085551313",
                "Country" : "USA"
            }
             ]
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks @notionquest. The docs seemed to indicate that I needed the "S". Taking them out works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without using quotes? Like that:

```
Keys: [
{"phone_num": {S:"+14085551212"}, "Country": {S:"USA"}},
{"phone_num": {S:"+14085551313"}, "Country": {S:"USA"}}
],
```

If the keys are of the String type, I can assure you it will work.